# Interface [key in StringEnum] when not all elements of StringEnum will exist as keys?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, mapped-types

Consider the following example data representing shops containing lists of pending and fulfilled purchase order ids:

```
{
    "shop-45": {
        "FULFILLED": [55, 70]
    },
    "shop-46: {
        "PENDING": [59, 54]
        "FULFILLED": [100, 101]
    }
}
```

If a shop has neither pending nor fulfilled orders, it does not appear in the list at all.

I attempted to represent this using the following:

```
type Status = "PENDING" | "FULFILLED";

interface ShopList {
    [shop: string]: {
        [status in Status]: number[];
    }
}
```

Unsurprisingly, `tsc` complains when I do not have *both* `PENDING` and `FULFILLED` as sub-properties of a shop.

I quelled the error by making that property optional (`[status in Status]?: number[]`) but I don't think that's really what I want to do, *since a shop will never have zero sub-properties*.

Another whimsical, shot-in-the-dark attempt `[status in Partial<Status>]: number[];` complains similarly.

Is that my only option, and simply not something to worry about?

This is a trivialized MCVE; the real one is far more complex and has more layers. That's (always?) the motivation behind using generics rather than repeating every possible key name: the enum is used as field values in other objects.

TypeScript/issues references discussing similar-seeming situations: [7374](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7374) | [19211](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19211) | [14934](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14934) | [5683](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5683).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to bar the scenario where a shop won't show up without either `PENDING` or `FULFILLED` you will need to be a little more explicit with your types. For instance, you could do the following:

```
type ShopWithPending = {
    PENDING: number[];
}

type ShopWithFulfilled = {
    FULFILLED: number[];
}

type ShopStatus = ShopWithPending | ShopWithFulfilled | (ShopWithPending & ShopWithFulfilled);

interface ShopList {
    [shop: string]: ShopStatus
}
```

However, this does make it hard to then use `shops` pulled out of the list, since Typescript will see the `ShopStatus` type as something that is not guaranteed to have any properties and will thus not allow you to deference `PENDING` or `FULFILLED`.

In order to get back that ability, you will need something else on the `Shop` types that allow Typescript to narrow back down the type inference to a specific typed version.

Comment: Thanks for this! It's very informative. I just modified the question to add more detail about thy I want to use a string enum (which I perhaps ought to have included initially): it's used elsewhere as a field value. It looks like this solution scales with difficulty when there are, say, 9 options?